# Contact Tracing Using Neo4j - Some people are not identified

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am developing a contact tracing framework using Neo4j. There are 2 types of nodes, namely **Person** and **Location**. There exists a relationship **VISITED** between a Person and a Location, which has properties **startTS** and **endTS**. Example:

[image]

If **Person 1** is infected, I need to retrieve all other **Person Nodes** who have been in direct or indirect contact with him using the graph database. I loop through all the relationships leading to a person node and apply a formula to determine if the ***current person*** (Person 2) was present at a particular location at the same time as the ***previous person*** (Person 1). This process is repeated for all person nodes identified. In the above picture, person 2 was in contact with person 1 based on their startTS and endTS. Here is my code:

```
MATCH path =(infected:Person {id:'1'})-[*]-(otherPerson:Person)
WITH RELATIONSHIPS(path) as rels,otherPerson
WHERE all(i in range(1,size(rels)-1)  WHERE (rels[i].endTS >= rels[i-1].startTS AND rels[i].startTS<= rels[i-1].endTS))
RETURN otherPerson
```

In the scenario below, person 1 infected person 2, and person 2 infected person 3. However, the code does not identify person 3 as infected, even though person 3 was clearly in contact with person 2. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate over the relationships and compare the timestamps of each relationship with its predecessor. However, you only want to compare the `VISITED` relationships between two persons `(Person)-[:VISITED]-(Location)-[:VISITED]-(Person)`. But in your approach, you are also comparing the relationships between two locations `(Location)-[:VISITED]-(Person)-[:VISITED]-(Location)`. A person could not have been at two locations at the same time.

So, you want to compare only every second pair of relationships. Since your are using an index, you can easily use the modulo operator, such that a relationship pair between two locations (or with one person) is always true:

```sql
MATCH path = (infected:Person {id:'1'})-[*]-(otherPerson:Person)
WITH relationships(path) as rels, otherPerson
WHERE all(i in range(1, size(rels)-1)
  WHERE i % 2 = 0
  OR (rels[i].endTS >= rels[i-1].startTS AND rels[i].startTS <= rels[i-1].endTS)
)
RETURN otherPerson
```

Comment: Hello, the query is taking way too long when there are tons of data. Is there any way to optimise it? @Brakebein

Comment: Yes, it's not very efficient. The current query looks for all paths and then filters them. Better would be to apply the filter (or WHERE) at each traversal step. [apoc.path.expand](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-querying/expand-paths-config/) does something like this, however you can only filter by node labels and relationship types. More complex filtering on property level are not supported. So, I don't know how to achieve this. Maybe you can limit the path lengths: `-[*..10]-` would only expand the path up to the 5th person.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will definitely look into that.