# Neo4j cypher - check in where statement foreach pair of path nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say that I am querying all paths as below:

```
MATCH p = (r:startNode)-[*]->(:endNode)
```

and it returns some paths like

```
A->B->C
A->D->E
```

What I would like to do is to check in where statement some conditions between node-node and relationship->node. I mean for example I would like to check does `B.someProperty == C.someProperty` and `relationFromB_To_C.property.Contains(C.otherProperty)`. How can I do it? Is there some easy way using cypher or should I switch to target SDK for C#?

Comment: I have recently answered some similar question. Maybe it helps with your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66528761/contact-tracing-using-neo4j-some-people-are-not-identified/66532165#66532165